# I installed python3.9.5, but it still shows 3.9.4 version

Tags: python-3.x, homebrew

I installed python3 by Homebrew. It says that python3.9.5 was successfully installed. But when i checked the version it shows python3.9.4. How can I fix it?
P.S. I.m using MacOs Big Sur.

[image: python]

Comment: Check near the installation location. You probably now have both versions installed, but the older version is the one accessible from your path. You'll have to update that.

Comment: Did you `source` your zshrc after installing?

Comment: @Kraigolas, you were right. I found an early version in Apps folder, removed to Trash and cleared it. Also cleared all symlinks and then tried again. Fixed. Thank you